# Tangent Space View Direction based factor value remap

Tags: mathematics, shaders, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to setup a mask similar to what Fresnel produces. Unfortunately Fresnel gives pretty bad results at grazing angles so I ended up using this :

```
float mask = abs(-viewDirTangentSpace.x / viewDirTangentSpace.z)
```

[image]

This gives a nice results but I would like to have values that evolves linearly. Is there a way to remap the range so it behaves like this (Photoshop) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDirTangentSpace.x` and `.z` form two sides of a right-angled triangle, so the `x/z` ratio you're calculating is the tangent ratio of an angle.

You can use the arctangent method to retrieve that angle in radians, in the range \$- \frac \pi 2\$ to \$+\frac \pi 2\$:

```
float angle = abs( atan(
  viewDirTangentSpace.x / viewDirTangentSpace.z
));
```

You can divide by pi and add a half to get it into the 0-1 range.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I ended up doing this `float mask = abs(atan(-viewDirTangentSpace.x / viewDirTangentSpace.z) / (PI * 0.5));`

Comment: Putting a minus sign inside an absolute value function doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yeah you're right !